# Не закрываются соединения к PostgreSql linq2db

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql

Всем привет. Столкнулся с проблемой при обращении к postgresql - при подгрузке данных из другой таблицы соединение не закрывается, даже если оборачиваю dbContext в using, без подгрузки данных из другой таблицы соединения корректно закрываются. Использую linq2db.

Вот собственно действие, которые вызывается:

```
[HttpGet]
    public PageModel<Client> GetAllClientInformation(WebApiEntityPageCondition<Client> condition)
    {
        using (var db = new HybridCrmEssence(GlobalConfig.Database.PostgreCrm))
        {
            var d = from cli in db.Clients.LoadWith(p => p.Contacts)
                    select cli;

            return new PageModel<Client>()
            {

                Items = d.ToArray()
            };
        }
    }
```

Контекст базы:

```
public class HybridCrmEssence : DataConnection
{
    public HybridCrmEssence(string connectionString) : base(new PostgreSQLDataProvider(), connectionString)
    {

    }

    public ITable<Client> Clients { get { return GetTable<Client>(); } }

    public ITable<Contact> Contacts { get { return GetTable<Contact>(); } } 
}
```

И сами модельки:

```
[Table("Clients")]
public class Client : DbModel
{


    [Association(ThisKey = "Id", OtherKey = "ClientId")]
    public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; } 

}
[Table("Contacts")]
public class Contact : DbModel
{

    [Column]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }

}
```

В DbModel у меня сам Id хранится. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в самой библиотек и автор исправил этот баг. По ссылке та самая проблема, где можно посмотреть коммит, который решил проблему. https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/issues/240.